# What does object.isQueryable() actually mean?

Tags: describesobject

What does is actually mean when a user  can 'query' an `Object`?

In other words: what rights does a user have when the `Object.isQueryable()` returns True?

Pages like [this](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_isQueryable) only say that `isQueryable` returns whether the user can 'query' the object. But what does that mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

isQueryable means the object is queryable as a top level object, e.g. you can do

```
select id from Foo__c
```

Some objects, e.g. Name are marked as isQueryable=false, and are only accessiable as a relationship from another object, so trying to do

```
select id from name
```

will return an error "entity type Name does not support query", but you can do

```
select who.name from event
```

(the polymorphic who relationship points to name during query)

Comment: And do rights come into play here? I see that I get isQueryable=false for a user with CRUD on a custom object and isQueryable=true for an admin, with the same CRUD rights on that custom object...

Comment: No, rights have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Ok. Could you come up with another explanation of the behaviour I get? I'm a little stuck there...

Comment: Some objects are only directly queryable as a top level object if you're an admin (and so sharing checks can be skipped).

Comment: This was with a custom object, so I would assume that is not the case here. But I'll look into that later. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

isQueryable() is used to check if application developers can carry out valid SOQL. Also it Returns true if the object can be queried by the current user, false otherwise.