# isAccessible() vs isQueryable() and which one to use for SOQL query CRUD checks

Tags: security-review, crud

Whats the difference between isAccessible() vs isQueryable() methods in DescribeSObjectResult Class and which method should one use for CRUD checks in SOQL query ?

(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm)

From documentation they look synonymous .

Answer (score 5):

1. You should use isAccessible() for read check.
2. isCreateable() to check whether object record is creatable
3. isUpdateable() to check whether a user can update record.
4. isDeletable() to check whether a user can delete record.

For isQueryable() detail see  [What does object.isQueryable() actually mean?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54322/what-does-object-isqueryable-actually-mean)